# Requirement for continuity of $f~'$ in the expansion of Taylors formula to measure error

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Assume $f$ has a continuous second derivative $f~''$ in some neighborhood of $a$.Then, for every $x$ in this neighborhood, we have $f(x) = f(a) + f~'(a)(x-a) + E_1(x)$ , where

$$E_1(x) = \int_a^x (x-t)f~''(t)dt$$

**Derivation**: $E_1(x) = f(x)-f(a) - f~'(a)(x-a) = \int_a^x f~'(t)dt - f~'(a)\int_a^x dt = \int_a^x[f'(t)-f'(a)]dt$

Using integration by parts ( take $u = f~'(t)-f~'(a) , dv =dt= d(t-x)$, we get :

$E_1(x) = \int_a^x (x-t)f~''(t)dt$.

I understand why $f~''$ must be continuous owing to the fundamental theorem of calculus applicable to the expression : $E_1(x) = \int_a^x (x-t)f~''(t)dt$

However, shouldn't $f~'(x)$ be also continuous as we have expressed :

> $f(x)-f(a) - f~'(a)(x-a) = \int_a^x f~'(t)dt - f~'(a)\int_a^x dt = \int_a^x[f'(t)-f'(a)]dt$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, must not $f~'(t)$ be also continuous as $f(x)-f(a)  = \int_a^x f~'(t)dt?$

Thank you for reading through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general differentiability $\implies$ continuity.

So if the second derivative $f''$ exists, then $f'$ is continuos

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I feel silly

Comment: @ShreyaTaneja You're welcome :) Everybody forgets simple stuff from time to time :-)